# Spring Annotation missing requestBody

Tags: java, post, controller, postman

I wrote a very simple controller class with a simple post and get method.

Today is my first time using Postman - I don't know what I am doing wrong but every time using a **POST** mapping, I am getting:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-03-29T19:05:49.548+0000",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Required request body is missing: public int pl.futurecollars.controller.GreetingControler.saveGreeting(pl.futurecollars.controller.Greeting)",
  "path": "/greetings"
}
```

Controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/greetings")
public class GreetingControler {

    private Map<Integer, Greeting> greetings = new HashMap<>();
    private int counter = 0;

    @GetMapping
    public Collection<Greeting> getGreetings() {
        return greetings.values();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public int saveGreeting(@RequestBody Greeting greeting){
        greeting.setId(counter);
        greetings.put(counter, greeting);
        return counter++;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void deleteGreeting(@PathParam("id") int greetingId){
        greetings.remove(greetingId);
    }
}
```

I added a `@RequestBody` but it still saying that it's missing.

**How to solve this trouble?**

Comment: By *sending* a request body! (postman/curl/...?)

Comment: How does `Greeting` class look like? How do you form your request?

Comment: curl = curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{... greeting json ...}' http://localhost:8080/greetings
{"timestamp":"2020-03-29T19:19:03.648+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('.' (code 46)): was expecting double-quote to start field name; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('.' (code 46)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 3]","path":"/greetings"}j

Comment: ..of course I hoped, you will help out/think with me about `{... greeting json ...}`... i used it just as a placeholder :) ..we don't know how a Greeting looks like.

Comment: @nazar_art - Greeting class is really simple : two fields , empty default constructor, getters and setters.

Comment: But in postman, you'd have to enter a valid greeting  (JSON) into the content pane of "Body tab" (selecting Json from the dropdown).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message has a distinct description of what is missing:

> Required request body is missing: ...

Therefore you missed adding a body to the request.

Your configuration should look like:

[image]

The body should be exactly the JSON object of your `Greeting` class.
It should be posted to the `raw` tab.

Also, don't forget about appropriate **Content-Type** at `header`:

[image]

***Useful links:***

- [Postman tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/postman-tutorial.html)
- [API testing using Postman](https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/api-testing-using-postman-323670c89f6d)

Answer (score 0):

First validate your input as per error that you mentioned in comment one of your fieldname is starting with `.` instead it should be in `""`. You can validate your json on https://jsoneditoronline.org/ .
Also adding postman snapshot just FYI
[Inside postman -> Body where u can put payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpYIQ.png)